# Timer which fires every 5 secs

Tags: android

How can i have timer which runs for every 5 secs continously.
below is the code snippet::

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask  = new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("adad","asdadsa");
}
};
timer.schedule(timerTask,0,5);
```

Comment: see this [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29] for more info for timer and put time in like 5 secs means 5000 instead of 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Timer timer= new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("adad","asdadsa");
  }
};
timer.schedule(timerTask,0,5000);
```

few minor changes check it...

Comment: Thanks that is what i want exactly